# include custom render code from another file in App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i bring a partial code not react component from another file?

Thanks

```
{this.state.test &&
<View>......</View> // i want to bring this code from another file here  with a shortcut import etc
}
```

Comment: You can create a custom component on the same file.

Comment: no, i do not want component, i have states and functions in one component , i just want to switch views, i want to put vies in file

Comment: Make the component that has the state be the parent component. And then wrap it around the views.

Comment: You can make a function that returns components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can organise these kind of code into a helper function, e.g. UIHelper.js:

```
function renderImageIcon(iconName, width = 32, height = 32, tintColor) {
    return (<Image
                source={localImageUrl[iconName]}
                style={[{
                    width: width,
                    height: height,
                    tintColor: tintColor
                }]}
            />)        
}

const UIHelper = {
    renderLabel: renderLabel,           //Other helper functions
    renderImageIcon: renderImageIcon,   //Expoert this
    renderDateTime: renderDateTime,     //Other helper functions
    ...
}
export default UIHelper;
```

Usage:

```
import UIHelper from '../what/ever/path/UIHelper'

render (){
...
   {UIHelper.renderImageIcon("search", 40, 40)}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import components from another file.

1-) Create component folder that includes your view codes and index file like;

```
-components
--MyView.js
--index.js

-App.js
```

2-) Fill your MyView class with what you want to see in your App.js like;

**MyView.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyView extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   render() {
      <View>...<View>
   }
}

MyView.propTypes = {
  props you want to use it...
};

module.exports = MyView;
```

**index.js**

```
import MyView from './components';

module.exports = {
  MyView,
};
```

3-)Import your MyView class into your App.js and use it like;

**App.js**

```
import { MyView } from './components';

{this.state.test &&
<MyView>...give some props that you want to see here...</MyView>
}
```

Importing your view or components from outside is useful when you want to use them in many pages and you should give specific props like style values or some data. Otherwise if you use just one time, it is not necessary at all.